# Bigquery UNNEST ARRAYS

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I wanna list of item_name, but contentType must be "POI"

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfTez.jpg

```
select param.item_name from 'dataset', 
UNNEST(event_params) AS param
where event_name  = "select_content" AND param.value.string_value = "POI"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ( SELECT value.string_value
    FROM UNNEST(event_params) param
    WHERE key = 'item_name'
  ) AS item_name
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(event_params) param
  WHERE (key, value.string_value) = ('content_type', 'POI') OR key = 'item_name'
  ) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your repley Mikhail. 
But I still don't get item_name where content_type = "POI". The query also return item_name, where content_type is e.g. "ROUTE" [1] https://imgur.com/a/7aaCjom

Comment: this cannot be a case  - so you should check what exactly you are running!! or your data might be not what you showed in your question